# Outlook VSTO - retrieve the meeting organizer

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I'm developing one add-in to book rooms in my organization.
Actually i'm stuck with one problem: With the GetFreeBusy method i get the availability of each room, but i need also to know: if the room is busy for someone, who is the organizer of these meeting? How can i get these information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get a corresponding `Recipient` (see the `Organizer` property) and use `objRecipient.GetFreeBusy` method which returns a string representing the availability of the recipient for a meeting over a specified period of time.